# Is it possible to alias multiple names in a numpy record array?

Tags: numpy

Suppose I construct a numpy record array like this

```
num_rows = <whatever>
data = np.zeros(
    (num_rows,),
    dtype={
        'names':['apple', 'banana'],
        'formats': ['f8', 'f8']
    }
```

Now I can access data either by name or index.
For example, the following are the same:

```
data['banana'][0]
```

and

```
data[0]['banana']
```

etc.
Is there a way to alias different names?
For example, can I set things up so that there's another name `manzana` such that

```
data['manzana']
```

is the same thing as

```
data['apple']
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

['offsets' and 'titles' are 2 mechanisms for giving different names to fields]

There is an `offset` parameter that can function in this way.  Usually it is used to split another field into several pieces (e.g. an int into bytes).  But it also works with identical fields.  In effect it defines several fields with overlapping data.

```
In [743]: dt=np.dtype({'names':['apple','manzana','banana','guineo'],
       'formats':['f8','f8','f8','f8'], 
       'offsets':[0,0,8,8]})

In [745]: np.zeros((3,),dtype=dt)
Out[745]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype={'names':['apple','manzana','banana','guineo'], 
        'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8','<f8'], 
        'offsets':[0,0,8,8], 'itemsize':16})

In [746]: A=np.zeros((3,),dtype=dt)

In [747]: A['banana']=[1,2,3]

In [748]: A
Out[748]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  
       (0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0), 
       (0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype={'names':['apple','manzana','banana','guineo'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,0,8,8], 'itemsize':16})

In [749]: A['guineo']
Out[749]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])

In [750]: A['manzana']=[.1,.2,.3]

In [751]: A['apple']
Out[751]: array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3])

In [752]: A
Out[752]: 
array([(0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 1.0),  
       (0.2, 0.2, 2.0, 2.0), 
       (0.3, 0.3, 3.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype={'names':['apple','manzana','banana','guineo'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8','<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,0,8,8], 'itemsize':16})
```

---

There's another dtype parameter, `titles` that is better suited to your needs, and easier to understand:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

```
In [792]: dt1=np.dtype({'names':['apple','banana'],'formats':['f8','f8'], 'titles':['manzana', 'guineo'], 'offsets':[0,8]})

In [793]: A1=np.zeros((3,),dtype=dt1)

In [794]: A1
Out[794]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[(('manzana', 'apple'), '<f8'), (('guineo', 'banana'), '<f8')])

In [795]: A1['apple']=[1,2,3]

In [796]: A1['guineo']=[.1,.2,.3]

In [797]: A1
Out[797]: 
array([(1.0, 0.1), (2.0, 0.2), (3.0, 0.3)], 
      dtype=[(('manzana', 'apple'), '<f8'), (('guineo', 'banana'), '<f8')])

In [798]: A1['banana']
Out[798]: array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3])
```

Comment: I get the idea but I don't understand the particulars here. It looks like `banana` and `guineo` have offsets of 8. How is that making `apple` and `manzana` share data? I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: With the same offset, `apple` and `manzana` are different fields that share data.  But I found `titles` which is closer to your idea of aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the answer of @hpaulj into a simple method and share it here in case someone wants to use it.

```
def add_alias(arr, original, alias):
    """
    Adds an alias to the field with the name original to the array arr.
    Only one alias per field is allowed.
    """

    if arr.dtype.names is None:
        raise TypeError("arr must be a structured array. Use add_name instead.")
    descr = arr.dtype.descr

    try:
        index = arr.dtype.names.index(original)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("arr does not have a field named '" + str(original) 
                         + "'")

    if type(descr[index][0]) is tuple:
        raise ValueError("The field " + str(original) + 
                         " already has an alias.")

    descr[index] = ((alias, descr[index][0]), descr[index][1])
    arr.dtype = np.dtype(descr)
    return arr

def add_name(arr, name):
    """
    Adds a name to the data of an unstructured array.
    """

    if arr.dtype.names is not None:
        raise TypeError("arr must not be a structured array. "
                        + "Use add_alias instead.")
    arr.dtype = np.dtype([(name, arr.dtype.name)])
    return arr
```